# Ubuntu 13.04 on macbook pro retina boots to black screen after apt-get upgrade

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 into a partition on the hard drive on my MacBook Pro 15'' with Retina Display. I used [this](http://randomtutor.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/installing-ubuntu-1304-on-retina.html) tutorial to install it. I then ran apt-get update and upgrade. After that I purged the nvidia packages and installed nvidia-current because I had problems with virtual versions of 13.04 and I thought it might help. Now when i boot up my Ubuntu partition it displays some white text before going to a black screen. Holding shift or pressing alt-ctrl-F1 does nothing. Is there any way to get into it to fix it? If not when I reinstall it how should I do it so this doesn't happen again? If you don't know is there a way I can save the state of my os before I run upgrade so I don't have to keep reinstalling it every time I try something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use nvidia current as you are on a Hybrid system with iGPU + dGPU you need to install the following:

sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime

The nvidia-prime is what bumblebee used to be and it's called nvidia optimus.

Hope you get your problem fixed.

Comment: I tried to install nvidia-prime but apt-get said that it could not find the package. I looked into it and it seems that it is not available for 13.04. If it helps this is the graphics card that I use: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB.